# Exercise about derivability and continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Given $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $f:[a,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ continous and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=f(a)$. Knowing $f$ is derivable onto $(a,\infty)$ prove that exists $x_0 > a$ so that $f'(x_0)=0$

If $f$ is a constant function the thesis is obvious. But in the other case I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: The grammatically correct expression in English is "$f$ is differentiable on $(a,\infty)$".

Comment: @user515933 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Assuming that $f(x)$ is not constant (trivial case), by [**IVT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) and [**EVT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) we can show that $f(x)$ has maximum or a minimum for some $x_0\in (a,\infty)$ and then $f'(x_0)=0$.

Comment: But how do you use the hypothesis of the function limit?

Comment: @user515933 If the interval of definition was a compact we could directly conclude by EVT but it is not the case. Then, assuming $f(x)$ is not constant, exists some $b\in (a,\infty)$ such that $f(b)\neq f(a)$. Assume wlog $f(b)>f(a)$ and take $f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$ then by IVT exist $x_1\in (a,b)$ and $x_2\in (b,\infty)$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(c)$ and by EVT for the restriction of the function onto $[x_1, x_2]$ exists a maximum at a point $x_0\in (x_1, x_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

Assume $f'(x) \not =0$ for  $x>a$.

Then $f' >0$, or $f' <0$ for $x >a$.

1) Consider $f' >0$:

Then $f$ is strictly monotonically increasing.

For $x_1 >a$ , we have $f(x_1) >f(a)$.

For $x >x_1$ : $f(x) >f(x_1)>f(a).$

We are given:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=f(a)$, i.e.

for  $\epsilon >0$:

There is $K$, real, positive, such that for $x > K$

$|f(x)-f(a)| \lt \epsilon$, or

$ -\epsilon +  f(a) < f(x) < f(a) +\epsilon.$

Choose $\epsilon =f(x_1) - f(a)$ $(>0)$.

Let $K':= \max (K,x_1)$,

for $x \gt K' :$

$f(x)<f(a)+\epsilon = f(x_1)$ ,

a contradiction.

Hence $f'(x) \le 0$ for a $x >a$.

1) If $f'(x) = 0$ for a $x >a$ , we are finished.

2) If $f'(x) <0$ for a $x >a$, need continuity(??) of the derivative to infer $f'(x) = 0$ for a $x >a.$

Answer (score 0):

For non-constant  $f$.

(1). Suppose there exists $b>a$ such that $f(b)>f(a).$ Since f is  continuous on $[a,b]$ there exists $c\in (a,b)$ with $f(c)=(f(a)+f(b))/2.$

Since $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=f(a)$ there exists $d>b$ with $f(d)<f(a)+\delta ,$ where $\delta =(f(b)-f(a))/2.$ That is, $f(d)<(f(a)+f(b))/2.$

Since $f$ is continuous on $[b,d]$ and $f(b)>(f(a)+f(b))/2>f(d),$ there exists $e\in (b,d)$ with $f(e)=(f(a)+f(b))/2.$

We now have $a<c<e$ and $f(c)=f(e),$ and since   f is differentiable on $(a,\infty),$ there exists  (by Rolle's Theorem) $x_0\in (c,e)$ with $f'(x_0)=0.$

(2). If $f(b)< f(a)$ for some $b>a$ then this is handled similarly to (1) and I will leave the details to you.

Comment: Intuitively, if  $b>a$ and $f(b)\ne f(a)$ then as $x$ moves from $b$ to $a,$ the value $f(x)$  moves continuously  from $f(b)$ to $f(a),$ so $f$  has to take the value $(f(a)+f(b))/2$ at some point $c\in  (a,b).$.. And as $x$ moves from $b$ towards $\infty,$ the value $f(x)$ moves continuously, starting at $f(b),$ and is eventually closer to $f(a)$ than  to $(f(a)+f(b))/2 ,$ so $f$ has to take the value $(f(a)+f(b))/2$ at some at some point $e\in (b,\infty).$